# Shouldn't there be a Windows Application for Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

How about we have a Windows application for Stack Overflow? I'm talking about a Desktop/Laptop/Notebook etc. application and not a Windows Phone application.

It could offer faster browsing, easy access, and a better UI. What do you say?

And if there shouldn't be a website and we can all pack our android phones and use web browsers, why is there an android application?

Comment: Just to be clear... You're asking for a desktop version of the website? How will that help? How would it be faster? Easier?

Comment: Because, it won't load all the stuff that is currently loading and, just to be clear, not every place in the world boasts of 100mbps Internet speed.

Comment: Votes on meta.SE simply mean disagreement with your proposal. **Do not take them personally.** (I think this is the 100000000 time this kinda comment is being posted)

Comment: Have you seen the Android Application of SE?

Comment: It doesn't load the related, section, doesn't load anythingother than what is requested, like, if you are browsing a question, you see the question, and not the related section and other stuff, like SE ads and stuff.

Comment: Adds are part of what makes these websites free to use. Did you try the mobile version? Works on desktops, probably a bit lighter. (Mobile link in the footer.)

Comment: if [this isn't what you want](http://stackapps.com/questions/3800/metrose-a-windows-8-stack-exchange-app) you can start your own project using the StackAPI to build a desktop application for windows.

Answer (score 4):

There should only be an app if it adds something to the platform.

The usability options available on iOS and Android are the primary reason there is an SE app in the first place (next to: it's cool to have one!).

What would an SE app on the Windows platform add? Or on any Linux platform? Not that much. Maybe there is an alternative way to show notifications, or to integrate with the OS, but no, we don't really need that.

I think the web site works fine on desktops, and even when mobile, I tend to use the mobile web app. There isn't a real need for an app.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: @Tim Indeed. Where is that for IE? There isn't an universal way to do this yet.

Comment: Hmm probably non existent...

Comment: Indeed. That's why I said "alternative way". There is a way as you described, but it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use one of these ready made programs:

- [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/)
- [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- [IE (eww)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/download-ie)
- [Safari](https://www.apple.com/uk/safari/)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)

What advantage would using up hard drive space, installation time and Windows installation bugginess over visiting [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) website?

What features would there be that would make this good?

---

[From the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255901/shouldnt-there-be-a-windows-application-for-stack-overflow/255902#comment833309_255901) I understand you want a site that doesn't update?

Easy - use [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/betafish-adblocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom), or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save the HTML page.

Comment: Then why is there an android application?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni A phone is different to a computer. It has a smaller screen, harder-to-use keyboard, slower internet. That's why it would be *easier* to use a phone app.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni because people us apps. Mobiles are likely to have slow internet speeds, etc. Also, optimising a website for mobile and desktop isn't easy - so they create a whole new way of accessing it. But you seem to want an offline version of the site? Screenshot it or save it.

Comment: Responsive Design.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni that easy is it? :P lol, what about all the coding behind it, the cookies, the images, the difficulty typing, the size of the text. what about the JS that controls almost everything here...

Comment: So you are trying to say, if the website is complex, well, then responsive design can go to hell. Wow.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni no, I'm saying it's easier to use other methods...? Are you misunderstanding? Maybe the answer above clarifies it.